# notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android, listview, adapter

My app uses a `MultiColumnListView` (https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView) and as its name says it helps creating multi column list views.

The library is great, but as they specify, filtering is not supported.

So I am trying to create my own text-filter functionality with a simple edit text.

Finally I achieve to filter the list but now I need to refresh the listView and recall the setAdapter because I pass the list on it.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,myList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I execute `listView.invalidateViews()` or `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the listView is refreshed but with the old list.

Which is the best way of recalling the setAdapter? or maybe is another way of doing this..

Thanks in advance

***EDIT:***

```
//Method that filters the list
Log.i("On filter myList.size()",""+myList.size());      
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//on the Adapter
Log.i("On Adapter myList.size()",""+myList.size());
```

***Log:***

[image]

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class MiAdaptadorListaComercios extends BaseAdapter{

//Textview and Imageviews declarations

private Context contexto;

private List<Comercio> myList;

public MiAdaptadorListaComercios(Context c,List<Comercio> myList){
    this.contexto = c;
    this.myList = new ArrayList<Comercio>();
    this.myList = myList;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.i("On Adapter myList.size()",""+listaComercios.size());
    return myList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return myList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View view =null;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cell, null);
    }
    else{
        view = convertView;
    }

    //set views Texteviews text,font etc...

    return view;
}
```

}

**Activity Class:**

```
public class ListaComercio extends Activity {

    private MultiColumnListView mAdapterView = null;
    EditText searchBar;
    private ArrayList<Comercio> myList;
    private ArrayList<Comercio> filteredList;
    MyAdapter adapter;


    public ListaComercio(){
        myList = new ArrayList<Comercio>();
        filteredList = new ArrayList<Comercio>();       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_comercios);

        mAdapterView = (MultiColumnListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(ListaComercio.this,myList);

        mAdapterView.setAdapter(adapter);


        searchBar.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    CharSequence filer =  v.getText();

                    for(Comercio co : myList)
                    {
                        if(co.getName().contains(filer))
                        {
                            filteredList.add(co);
                        }
                    }

                    myList = filteredList;

                    Log.i("On filter myList.size()",""+myList.size());  

                    myList.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //mAdapterView.invalidateViews();

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: also post your activity code where u set this adapter

Comment: thank you, I have just add it @MD

Comment: Here is the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479071/1084174

Answer (score 21, accepted):

just change your `myList` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` don't set a new adapter each time.

In the constructor of your custom adapter do call `super` that takes ArrayList as the argument.

call this:

```
public MiAdaptadorListaComercios(Context c,List<Comercio> myList){
    super(c,0,myList);
    this.contexto = c;
    this.myList = myList;
}
```

You can keep the adapter as it is the problem is in this line:

```
myList = filteredList;
```

instead of changing the reference you should change the list itself.

```
myList.clear();
myList.addAll(filteredList);
```

By doing this you will loose your original list to I would suggest keeping another list call ed originalList which will have the complete list and initialize myList in onCreate by:

```
myList=new ArrayList(originalList);
```

so every time you want to re-set just call:

```
myList.clear();
myList.addAll(originalList);
```

and in

```
    for(Comercio co : originalList)
            {
                if(co.getName().contains(filer))
                {
                    filteredList.add(co);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, for answering that fast, but that is what I am doing and it is not working. I have edited my question to specify that

Comment: share your MyAdapter class as well

Comment: thanks again. But when I call `super()` on the constructor nothing changes and if I try to call `super(myList)` I get an error telling that I must remove the argument to match `BaseAdapter`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I am getting this error on the eclipse [errorImage1](http://postimg.org/image/6fvh0isct/) [errorImage2](http://postimg.org/image/9ji3yw3mv/). Even though I have edited the question and I have added the `Activity` which sets the adapter and the list, maybe the error is there. Thank you so much again

Comment: extend with ArrayAdapter instead

Comment: It works!! The problem was the List itself not the adapter. Thank You very much! You are a lifesaver!! :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to clear older `myList.clear()` and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

**Update:**

Change your code like:

```
public MiAdaptadorListaComercios(Context c,List<Comercio> myList){
this.contexto = c;
this.myList = new ArrayList<Comercio>();
}
```

Also, do it like

```
myList.clear();
myList.addAll(originalList);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it is not working.. I have edited my question and I've include more details. I hope that will hep you guessing what am I doing wrong

Comment: But when I do that the list is always empty... or should I add `this.myList = myList` after the new?