# RecyclerView notifyDatasetChanged not working when notifyDatasetchanged in anonymous class method

Tags: java, android

I am looking for the solution to my problem about how to refresh adapter without re-setting my RecyclerView adapter.
Through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165728/android-notifydatasetchanged-not-working) answer I have done but nothing work what am I do wrong.
Here is my code that set recyclerView adapter.

```
public class OrderedFoodsFragment extends Fragment
{
private NewInvoice invoice;
private List<InvoiceItem> items= new ArrayList<>();
private OrderedAdapter adapter;
public OrderedFoodsFragment(NewInvoice invoice)
{
    this.invoice = invoice;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ordered_foods, container, false);
    initializeComponents(view);
    return  view;
}

private void initializeComponents(View view)
{
    RecyclerView rvOrderedFoods = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvOrderedFoods);
    adapter= new OrderedAdapter(getActivity(), items,R.layout.ordered_layout);
    rvOrderedFoods.setAdapter(adapter);
    setInvoiceItems();
}

private void setInvoiceItems()
{
    IInvoiceApi api= ApiClient.getClientWithAuthorization(App.getContext()).create(IInvoiceApi.class);
    Call<List<InvoiceItem>> call= api.getInvoiceItems(invoice.getId());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<InvoiceItem>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<InvoiceItem>> call, @NonNull Response<List<InvoiceItem>> response)
        {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                //My comment code
                //items=response.body();
                //adapter= new OrderedAdapter(getActivity(), items,R.layout.ordered_layout);
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                items.clear();
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                items.addAll(response.body());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("InvoiceData", adapter.getItemAtPosition(0).getName());
            }
            else if (response.code() == 401)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Session Expire").setMessage("សិទ្ធក្នុងការប្រើកម្មវិធីអស់ពេល").show();
                App.promptUnauthorized(getActivity());
            }
            else
            {
                items= new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<InvoiceItem>> call, @NonNull Throwable t)
        {
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
}

}
```

I'm using retrofit 2.0 to request for my data.
And the response.body() has my data. But the recyclerview not show the data.
But if I re-set the adapter in the onRespose method to the response.body() as my comment code in this method it works but I don't want it like. Any solution help me.

Comment: See, you are directly putting the response.body() which is an object into the adapter , so how it can be shown! Instead of that ,check your JSON response , take the List of InVoiceItem from response and then apply to adapter

Comment: my json return my right data and and get my right object too.

Comment: can you please post your POJO class

Comment: Are you sure items get data that you added successfully? and check whether the block of code is called twice.

Comment: Does this line `Log.i("InvoiceData", adapter.getItemAtPosition(0).getName());` produce your expected output?

Comment: yes my line of log output right.

Comment: Oh... I know why that the item not show. It is my mistake I didn't set the Recyclerview layout manager yet. Sorry to bother you guys.

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this new list to the adapter.

You can create a setDataSet() method in your adapter and call it before notifydatasetchanged

Add below method in adapter

```
public void setDataSet(List<InvoiceItem> items) {
    this.items= items;
}
```

and call it before notifydatasetChanged like this:

```
adapter.setDataSet(items);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```