# notifyDatasetChanged() is not working in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

- `notifyDatasetChanged()` is not working, But instead of
  `notifydatasetChanged()`, if i pass the `eventList` with data to
  adapter directly after initializing `recyclerview` list loads fine.
- How to resolve this

---

**ActEvents.kt**

```
class ActEvents : AppCompatActivity(){

    // Initializing an empty ArrayList to be filled with animals
    var eventList: MutableList<TestModel> = ArrayList()

    @set:Inject var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    private lateinit var personDisposable: Disposable

    /******************* Life Cycle Methods *************************/
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initOnCreate()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        initOnDestroy()
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return true
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        initOnCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean { return initOnOptionsItemSelected(item) }
    /******************* Life Cycle Methods *************************/


    /******************** Subscribers *******************************/
    private fun setRxJavaRecievers() {

        personDisposable = RxBus.listen(RxEvent.RxEventList::class.java).subscribe {
            eventList = it.personName.getmData()
            event_list.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
    /******************** Subscribers *******************************/

    /******************* Init Methods *******************************/
    /** Init On Create **/
    private fun initOnCreate() {
        //Set up the UI
        setContentView(R.layout.act_events)
        //Inject Dagger Component
        (application as CaringApp).netComponent.inject(this)
        //Set up toolbar
        setToolbar()
        //Set up the recycler view
        initRecyclerView()
        //Set Rx java receivers
        setRxJavaRecievers()

    }



    /** Init On Destroy **/
    private fun initOnDestroy() {
        //Un Register disposable
        if (!personDisposable.isDisposed) personDisposable.dispose()
    }


    /** Initialize recyclerView **/
    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        event_list.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
        event_list.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        event_list.adapter = AdptEvents(eventList,this)
    }


    /******************* Init Methods *******************************/

}
```

**AdptEvents.kt**

```
class AdptEvents (val items: MutableList<TestModel>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_event, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.tvAnimalType.text = items[position].getName()
    }

}

class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
    val tvAnimalType = view.txtTitle!!
}
```

Comment: Could you try `eventList.clear()` and then `eventList.addAll(it.personName.getmData())` ?

Comment: Redman answered your question :D. The main reason is that the one(in Activity) and the one(in Apdapter) didn't keep the same reference of the list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: notifyDataSetChanged(); not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165728/android-notifydatasetchanged-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recyclerview `notifyDatasetChanged()` will work only until you don't change the reference of the list . But in your receiver you might be changing reference to the list

```
private fun setRxJavaRecievers() {

    personDisposable = RxBus.listen(RxEvent.RxEventList::class.java).subscribe {
        eventList = it.personName.getmData()
        event_list.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

so instead  do

```
 private fun setRxJavaRecievers() {

    personDisposable = RxBus.listen(RxEvent.RxEventList::class.java).subscribe {
        eventList.clear()
        eventList.addAll(it.personName.getmData())
        event_list.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

or set the adapter again to make it work